# Bootstrap ScrollSpy isn't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chiliyago/D2RLR/3915/) project I am using to test the [ScrollSpy feature of BootSTrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy)

The demo has 5 links to sections of the page and the links work.  However, scrolling down the page does not activate the nav menus.  Futhermore, I notice that upon running the jsfiddle the very last menu option in my nav is gray.  Because the first option in my nav is down the page a bit I would think no nave would be highlighed.

I am not seeing what I doing wrong??

```
<section class="navspy">
        <ul id="navigation" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked affix" style="width:200px">
            <li><a href="#patientInfo">Patient Info</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#EmergencyContactInfo">Emergency Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#EmploymentInfo">Employement Info</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#GuardianInfo">Guardian Info</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#InsuranceInfo">Insurance Info</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Thanks for you help.

Updated: 3/5/2013-JSFiddle link now correct

Comment: I dont see any link in your jsfiddle ?

Comment: Looks like I'll have to rebuild it.  #frustrating

Comment: Just remember when ya insert anything new hit CTRL + S to save it and than post that version here

Comment: I think it is updated now.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: can you please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the body tag in the following way :

Jsfiddle with [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/D2RLR/3916/)

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navspy">
```

you were using id navigation without # tag . Also for scrollspy to work use the section id to in the body for data-target.

Since you already have the data-spy and data-target specified in body tag no need to initialize via javascript .